# Li-ion charge / discharge circuit with ESP32 and MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, esp8266, discharge, charge, esp32

Here is what I’d like to do: Wire a circuit that can either charge or discharge a single li-ion cell (3.0 to 4.2 V) or just do nothing at all. An ESP32 controls the circuit (max. 3.3 V). An INA219 monitors current and voltage (but that is the least of my issues).

For charging, I am planning to use a TP4056 module which would be permanently connected to a USB power supply. For the discharge, I’ll be using a load resistor and a MOSFET (Q1) as variable load. This N-channel MOSFET also acts as a switch, to turn off the discharging process when pulled to ground. Here is the schematic:

[image: schematic]

I am pretty sure that the second N-channel MOSFET (Q2) would not work in this configuration. Probably a P-channel would do the job, but that I am not sure of and neither do I know if I can control a P-channel MOSFET by directly connecting it to a GPIO pin of the ESP32.

**Now my questions:**

1. Is there a way to change the circuit / place the second N-channel MOSFET so that it would work?
2. If not, would a P-channel MOSFET work and could I connect it directly to a GPIO pin of the ESP32?

Link to IRLZ44N data sheet:  https://asset.conrad.com/media10/add/160267/c1/-/en/000162877DS01/datenblatt-162877-infineon-technologies-irlz44npbf-mosfet-1-hexfet-110-w-to-220.pdf